# Awkward gap between menu items. How to fix?

Tags: php, html, css

I am having trouble with the layout of a website I'm making.
I'm not very good with CSS.

So the trouble I'm having is that I want to have a horizontal menu bar that I want to center in my website. This menu can have dropdown children.

The implementation is in jQuery.
So this is the HTML code of my menu bar :

```
<ul class='dropdown'>
    <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Incident</a>
        <ul class='sub_menu'>
            <li><a href='index.php?action=new'>New</a></li>
            <li><a href='index.php?action=edit'>Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href='index.php?action=manage'>Manage</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='action_logout.php'>Log out</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this is the CSS that is being implemented :

```
*                                   { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body                                { font: 14px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; margin: 15px; } 
a                                   { text-decoration: none; }
ul                                  { width: 800px; list-style: none; text-align: center; margin: auto; padding: 2px 2px;}
p                                   { margin: 15px 0; }
/* 
    LEVEL ONE
*/
ul.dropdown                         { position: relative; }
ul.dropdown li                      { display: inline; font-weight: bold; background: #ccc; padding: 2px 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #777; }
ul.dropdown a:hover              { color: #000; }
ul.dropdown a:active                { color: #ffa500; }
ul.dropdown li a                    { display: inline; padding: 2px 8px; border-right: 1px solid #777; border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
                                  color: #222; }
ul.dropdown li:last-child a         { border-right: none; } /* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li.hover,
ul.dropdown li:hover                { background: #F3D673; color: black; position: relative; }
ul.dropdown li.hover a              { color: black; }
/* 
    LEVEL TWO
*/
ul.dropdown ul                      { width: 175px; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; text-align: left; }
ul.dropdown ul li                   { font-weight: normal; background: #f6f6f6; color: #000; 
                                  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; float: none; }
                                /* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */
ul.dropdown ul li a                 { border-right: none; width: 100%; display: inline-block; }
```

**[An Example can be seen here.](http://jsfiddle.net/fPAFs/)**

I did manage to center my menu bar after all. However there seems to be a little gap between Home and Incident menus and I've no idea how to get rid of it.

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please find another title. I can't answer anything else than "take some aspirin" to a "X is giving me a headache" question. Your title should be descriptive of your actual programming problem.

Comment: Sorry, it really is =P. There, I changed it.

Comment: You may give us a link to your website or an image?

Comment: It's really awful how you give us PHP code which echoes html. How is php code even relevant? Can you please create a jsfiddle which demonstrates your problem and paste a link here?

Comment: @hermann: I've edited the question for you. Please give us HTML code and not PHP which echoes out HTML. Also, **this** is a descriptive title.

Comment: @Shedal my post has been fixed. Are there any other objections so you can remove your downvote? Please let me know.

Comment: @hermann Removed the downvote.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about this: http://dabblet.com/gist/2520870

Your code was a mess.

```
<style>
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin:  0;
    }

    body {
        font-family: helvetica, serif;
        font-size:   14px;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
        text-align: center;
        font-size:  0;
        margin:     15px;
    }

    ul.dropdown ul {
        width:      220px;
        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1.8em;
        left: 0;
    }

    ul.dropdown ul li a {
        font-weight:   normal;
        background:    #f6f6f6;
        color:         #000;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        float:         none;
    }

    .dropdown > li {
        display:   inline-block;
        height:    1.2em;
        font-size: 14px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .dropdown li a {
        display:         block;
        background:      rgb(204, 204, 204);
        border-bottom:   rgb(119, 119, 119) 1px solid;
        border-right:    rgb(119, 119, 119) 1px solid;
        padding: 0.3em;
        color:           rgb(0, 0, 0);
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight:     bold;
    }

    .dropdown li a:hover {
        background: rgb(243, 214, 115);
    }
</style>

<ul class='dropdown'>
    <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Incident</a>
        <ul class='sub_menu'>
            <li><a href='index.php?action=new'>New</a></li>
            <li><a href='index.php?action=edit'>Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href='index.php?action=manage'>Manage</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='action_logout.php'>Log out</a></li>
</ul>
```

Try this new code. Though I urge you to not try and implement someone else's code without understanding it first!

Comment: How does your drop down look like? You never gave any code that indicates how your dropdown works.

Comment: This is where I got it from : http://css-tricks.com/examples/SimplejQueryDropdowns/  I did edit the CSS a bit because although it looks centered, it actually isn't.

Comment: You're the only person that actually helped. I understand my post was a mess but most people decided to leave a witty remark rather than explain what I've done wrong or try to help me. Thank you.

Comment: @hermann: Sure. I'll repeat the last sentence in my answer:  I urge you to not try and implement someone else's code without understanding it first!.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you managed to put whitespace outside `<li>` element, here is absolutely same code with whitespace removed:
http://jsfiddle.net/fPAFs/1/